# Override display property inside animation

Tags: css, animation

I want to create a "fade-out" animation which also sets the display property to "none" at the end of the animation, as the component will be replaced by another component in its place. Here is the css for the component and animation:

```css
.lock-container-exit {
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 5vh;
    justify-content: center;
    animation-name: fade-out;
    animation-delay: 1s;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes fade-out {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        display: none;
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

Edit:
The other component that will replace this component:

```css
.contact-info {
    width: fit-content;
    align-self: center;
    margin-top: 5vh;
    animation-name: fade-in;
    opacity: 0;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

However, it seems that the display property is not overwritten at the end of the animation. What is wrong here?

Comment: hi, Where is the other component?

Comment: maybe because opacity :0 and display: none collapse with each other. Have you tried using one of them?

Comment: I've edited to add the other component. Ideally it will simply take the position of the original container, but the original container is still there (display is still flex) after the animation.

Comment: It seems you can't do this with pure CSS https://www.impressivewebs.com/animate-display-block-none/ A quick solution is to add `99%{opacity:0}100%{opacity:0; height:0;width:0;}`

Answer (score 0):

I made two separate divs and made them replace each other. let me know if you need it in certain direction.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .div1 {
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      background-color: red;
      position: relative;
      animation-name: example;
      animation-duration: 2s;
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }
    
    @keyframes example {
      0% {
        background-color: red;
        left: 0px;
        top: 0px;
        opacity: 1;
      }
      100% {
        background-color: red;
        left: 205px;
        top: 0px;
        opacity: 0;
      }
    }
    
    .div2 {
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      background-color: gold;
      position: relative;
      animation-name: example2;
      animation-duration: 3s;
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }
    
    @keyframes example2 {
      0% {
        position: absolute;
        background-color: gold;
        left: 0px;
        top: 201px;
        opacity: 0;
      }
      100% {
        position: absolute;
        background-color: gold;
        left: 0px;
        top: 0px;
        opacity: 1;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>



  <div class="div1"></div>
  <div class="div2"></div>



</body>

</html>
```